# Android viewpager call setcurrentitem without onPageSelected

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have a viewPager with images and text in my android app, my target is to create a runnable to let this view pager scroll automatically, and my other target is when user click on one item in this viewpager i need to go to another activity.

This is my runnable:

```
        final Handler handler = new Handler();

        final Runnable Update = new Runnable() {


            public void run() {
                if (currentPage == NUM_PAGES - 1) {
                    currentPage = -1;
                }
                pager.setCurrentItem(currentPage++,true);
               pager.setScrollBarFadeDuration(R.styleable.CirclePageIndicator_fillColor);
               pager.setScrollDurationFactor(4);
                mIndicator.setCurrentItem(currentPage++);
            }
        };

        swipeTimer = new Timer();
        swipeTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                handler.post(Update);
            }
        }, 1000, 3000);
```

the problem is that every time the runnable call "SetCurrentItem()" the onpageselected function is called and then the activity is opened. So how can i prevent the onpageselected to be called when calling setCurrentItem every 3 seconds?

```
            pager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Picture current = (Picture)pageAdapter.getItem(arg0);
                Article a = getArticleById(current.getArticleId(), p);
                Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setClass(HomePageActivity.this,DetailActivity.class);
                //.getString(tag))); 
                bundle.putParcelable("article", a);
                bundle.putParcelableArrayList("pic", a.getPic());
                intent.putExtras(bundle);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
                startActivity(intent);

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                currentPage=arg0;
                //mIndicator.setCurrentItem(arg0);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add a click listener to your ViewPager items inside of your adapter. `onPageSelected` method doesn't listen click events.

In `instantiateItem` method of your ViewPager adapter, do this:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) collection.getContext()
        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_layout, null);

rootView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View v){
        //do the click thing
    }
});

container.addView(rootView);
return rootView;
```

Comment: Its working but not on the whole layout, i make onclicklistener for the imageview only

Comment: You can modify it depending on what you need. You can also use your own listener if you want to manage click events from your Activity/Fragment.